# python replace word in text file without going line by line

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-files

I have a text file, say:

```
This is a text document
written in notepad
```

I want to replace 'document' with the word 'file' and 'notepad' with the word 'Notepad' and then I want to save / override the file. Now, without going line by line, because I know I can do

```
wordReplacements = {'document':'file', 'notepad':'Notepad'}
contents = open(filePath, 'r')
for line in contents:
    for key, value in wordReplacements.iteritems():
        line = line.replace(key, value)
contents.close()
```

but is there a way to do it without going line by line? 
Note: I am using python 2.7.

Comment: Quoting from [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html), `For reading lines from a file, you can loop over the file object. This is memory efficient, fast, and leads to simple code`

Comment: You could probably use re.sub for the entire document, but line by line is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects),

> For reading lines from a file, you can loop over the file object. This
>   is memory efficient, fast, and leads to simple code

So, I were you, I would have done it like this

```
import os
wordReplacements = {'document':'file', 'notepad':'Notepad'}

def transform_line(line):
    for key, value in wordReplacements.iteritems():
        line = line.replace(key, value)
    return line

with open("Output.txt", "w") as output_file, open("Input.txt") as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        output_file.write(transform_line(line))

os.rename("Output.txt", "Input.txt")
```

If you prefer one-liners, you replace the `with` part with this

```
with open("Output.txt", "w") as output_file, open("Input.txt") as input_file:
    output_file.write("".join(transform_line(line) for line in input_file))
```

If memory is not a problem and you still want not to iterate over the file object, you can have the contents of the entire file moved to memory and then replace it there

```
import re
with open("Input.txt") as open_file:
    data = open_file.read()
for key, value in wordReplacements.iteritems():
    data = re.sub(key, value, data)
with open("Input.txt", "wb") as open_file:
    open_file.write(data)
```

Comment: hm, if I do data.close() right now, will it save and override the existing Input.txt? Because that is what I want to do

Comment: hm, okay so it would be more efficient if I did "for line in open_file: for key, value in wordReplacements.iteritems(): line = line.replace(key, value)" and then "open_file.close()" and that would save the file?

Answer (score 2):

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
  words = f.read().replace("foo", "bar")

with open(sys.argv[1], "wb") as f:
  f.write(words)
```

Comment: Why are you setting `words` to None first? :/

Comment: @Claris hm, how come we are opning the file in binary mode (wb)? Do we need to, or can we just open it with (w)? Also, does f automatically get closed after "words = f.read().replace("foo", "bar")"?

Comment: Text mode is better for a text file.  The "with" statement will close the file when its no longer needed.

Comment: @Wooble: words = None is style, not needed. Updated code to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

With similar code,it's also possible to use re.sub method available in the re module to substitute based on the regular expression. However, using this method would require traversing the file content N times if you need to replace N patterns.